# Load a highcharts graph with a json file

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to load a a graph inside my document.ready function after an ajax call.

The JSON is generated via php and the result is this:

[{"name":"Precios","data":[["5.50","2013-07-01 13:50:00"],["6.50","2013-07-05 11:04:00"]]}]

I am trying to graph the data part of the json using this code:

```
var options = {
chart: {
        renderTo: 'graphContainer',
    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
    marginRight: 130,
    marginBottom: 25
},

title: {
    text: 'Registro de Precios',
    x: -20 //center
},
    subtitle: {
    text: 'Producto: '+nombreProducto,
    x: -20 //center
},

xAxis: {
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
    text: 'Fecha'
    }
},

yAxis: [
    {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Precio'
    }
    },
    {
    linkedTo: 0,
        opposite: true
    }
],

legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -10,
    y: 100,
    borderWidth: 0
},

series: []
};  
$jDatepicker.getJSON('graficasDatos.php?idTienda='+idTienda+'&idProducto='+idProducto, function(data) {          

    $jDatepicker.each(data, function(key, value) {
var series = {};
$jDatepicker.each(value, function(key,val) {
    if(key == 'name')
    {
    series.name = val;
    }
    else{
    var datos;
    $jDatepicker.each(val, function(key,val) {
        datos = val;
        var x = datos[1];
        var y = datos[0];
        series.data = [x,y];
        options.series.push(series); 
    });
    }
});
});
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Any pointers as to what am I doing wrong or why is the graph not showing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dates should be timestamps (time in miliseconds) and values need to be number, not string.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I was able to get it to work, I just had to change the approach.

I modified the JSON to get this:

[{"rows":[{"precio":"5.50","fecha":"2013-07-01"},{"precio":"6.50","fecha":"2013-07-05"}],"fechas":[{"fecha":"2013-07-01"},{"fecha":"2013-07-05"}],"name":"Precio"}]

And this is the updated code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'graphContainer',
    showAxes: true,
    borderWidth: 1
},
title: {                    
        text: 'Precios registrados del producto'
},
credits: {
    text: 'GTSF'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    title: {
    text: 'Fecha',
    align: 'high'
    },
    labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    align : 'center',
    y: 40,
    x: -20
    },
    categories: []
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
    text: 'Precio ($)'
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    line: {
    allowPointSelect: true
    }
}
});

// Kick off the loading screen
chart.showLoading("Obteniendo precios de producto "+ nombreProducto +" ....");

$jDatepicker.getJSON('graficasDatos.php?idTienda='+idTienda+'&idProducto='+idProducto, function(stockData) {          

    // Construct series data and add the series
var seriesData = [];
var categoriesArray = [];

    $jDatepicker.each(stockData[0].rows, function(idx, data) {
    precio = parseFloat(data.precio);
    seriesData.push([ data.fecha, precio ]);
});

$jDatepicker.each(stockData[0].fechas, function(idx, data) {
    categoriesArray.push( data.fecha );
});

var seriesOpts = {
    name: stockData[0].name,
    data: seriesData,
    // This is to stop Highcharts rotating the color
    // for the series
    color: chart.options.colors[0],
    marker: {
        symbol: chart.options.symbols[0]
    }
}

chart.options.xAxis.categories = categoriesArray;

chart.hideLoading();
chart.addSeries(seriesOpts, false);
//chart.addAxis(axisOpts, true);
chart.redraw();
});
```

I hope this can help someone :D